# filesystem tree diagram shows strange iteration behaviour

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-trees, scripts

I found this (the one on the left) on [TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/filesystem-tree/).
I made the one on the right, based on the same code.
I was hoping I might be a be able to write a script to map out a real filesystem. I decided to start small. I tried to recreate it with a single `\foreach` loop, iterating over the list of names, but something strange happened, and it ended up looking like the third one (below) I can't figure out why it's nesting like that.
[image] 
[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=black,thick,anchor=west]
\tikzstyle{selected}=[draw=red,fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{optional}=[dashed,fill=gray!50]
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  grow via three points={one child at (0.5,-0.7) and
  two children at (0.5,-0.7) and (0.5,-1.4)},
  edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}]
  \node {texmf}
    child { node {doc}}     
    child { node {fonts}}
    child { node {source}}
    child { node [selected] {tex}
      child { node {generic}}
      child { node [optional] {latex}}
      child { node {plain}}
    }
    child [missing] {}              
    child [missing] {}              
    child [missing] {}              
    child { node {texdoc}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  grow via three points={one child at (0.5,-0.7) and two children at (0.5,-0.7) and (0.5,-1.4)}, 
  edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |-(\tikzchildnode.west)}]
  \node {/}
    child { node {bin}} 
    child { node {dev}} 
    child { node {etc}}
    child { node {home}}    
    child { node {lib}}
    child { node {media}}   
    child { node {mnt}} 
    child { node {opt}} 
    child { node {proc}}
    child { node {root}}    
    child { node {sbin}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  grow via three points={one child at (0.5,-0.7) and two children at (0.5,-0.7) and (0.5,-1.4)},
  edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |-(\tikzchildnode.west)}]
  \node {/} \foreach \x in {bin,dev,etc,home,lib,media,mnt,opt,proc,root,sbin}{
    child { node {\x}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe
instead of

```
\node{/} \foreach \x in {bin,dev,etc,home,lib,media,mnt,opt,proc,root,sbin}{
    child { node {\x}}};
```

```
\node {/} child [] foreach \name in {bin,dev,etc,home,lib,media,mnt,opt,proc,root,sbin} 
     {node {\name}};
```

More in Chapter 21 of TikZ Manual Book. Full working example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=black,thick,anchor=west]
\tikzstyle{selected}=[draw=red,fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{optional}=[dashed,fill=gray!50]
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  grow via three points={one child at (0.5,-0.7) and
  two children at (0.5,-0.7) and (0.5,-1.4)},
  edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}]

  \node {/} child [] foreach \name in {bin,dev,etc,home,lib,media,mnt,opt,proc,root,sbin} 
      {node {\name}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I'm too lazy to post a scrennshot, see my name:)

Comment: Wow that actually worked, thanks. You can use my screenshot if you want, I think it's identical.

Answer (score 1):

This is just to mention that one could use `forest`. If you really need to wrap it around a list, you may do so, too.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myforwrapper}[1]{[#1]}
\newcommand{\myfor}[2]{%
\edef#2{}%
\pgfutil@for\my@item:={#1}\do{%
\edef#2{#2\myforwrapper{\my@item}}%
}}
\newcommand{\MyDirectoryTree}[2][]{%
\myfor{#2}{\temp}%
\edef\temp{\noexpand\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=east,folder,draw}
[/
\temp
]
\noexpand\end{forest}}%
\temp}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\MyDirectoryTree{bin,dev,etc,home,lib,media,mnt,opt,proc,root,sbin}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how does that work with files and subdirectories (i.e. more levels)?

Comment: @voices You can convert pretty much any input to a hierarchical tree. Yet I do not know which input format you have in mind.